# Three JS GLTF Loader Not Working with Nuxt 3

Tags: three.js, vuejs3, vite, nuxtjs3, gltf

I'm facing an error when implementing three JS Gltf Loader with nuxt 3.
Error message :
" Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Class constructor Loader cannot be invoked without 'new' .. "

versions:

"three": "^0.148.0",
"three-gltf-loader": "^1.111.0"

```
<template>
  <div ref="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import * as THREE from "three";
import GLTFLoader from "three-gltf-loader";

export default {
  setup() {
    const container = ref(null);
    const scene = ref(new THREE.Scene());
    const renderer = ref(new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true }));
    const width = 700;
    const height = 700;
    const camera = ref(
      new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000)
    );
    const loader = ref(new GLTFLoader());
    onMounted(async () => {
      renderer.value.setSize(
        container.value.clientWidth,
        container.value.clientHeight
      );
      container.value.appendChild(renderer.value.domElement);
      camera.value.position.z = 5;
      const response = await fetch("logo.gltf");
      const gltf = await response.json();
      loader.value.parse(
        gltf,
        "",
        (gltf) => {
          scene.value.add(gltf.scene);
          renderer.value.render(scene.value, camera.value);
        },
        undefined,
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
    });

    return { container };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I had a similar error when placing a custom JS class (plain js file) into Nuxt's `\plugins` folder. Living there, it gets processed by whatever Nuxt does, thus triggering the error (probably to do with Typescript config's ES5 vs ES6 support). In any case, simply moving the offending custom script to folder `/assets/js` was all that was needed. Essentially, plain JS scripts shouldn't live in Nuxt `/plugins` unless you intend for it to actually be a Nuxt plugin =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on Alvaro Dev Labs' YT channel, he used TroisJS instead of ThreeJS ( in fact, it's Vite + Three).
And for nuxt 3 you just need to add ".client.vue " to the file name of your component to run it on the client side (Model.client.vue).

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import {
  Renderer,
  Scene,
  Camera,
  PointLight,
  AmbientLight,
  GltfModel,
} from "troisjs";
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Renderer,
    Scene,
    Camera,
    PointLight,
    AmbientLight,
    GltfModel,
  },
  setup() {
    const renderer = ref(null);
    const model = ref(null);

    function onReady(model) {
      console.log("Ready", model);
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      renderer?.value?.onBeforeRender(() => {
        model.value.rotation.x += 0.01;
      });
    });

    return {
      renderer,
      model,
      onReady,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <Renderer ref="renderer" antialias orbit-ctrl resize="window">
      <Camera :position="{ x: -10, z: 20 }" />
      <Scene background="#fff">
        <AmbientLight />
        <PointLight
          color="white"
          :position="{ x: 100, y: 1000, z: 40 }"
          :intensity="1"
        />
        <GltfModel ref="model" src="/Models/logo.gltf" @load="onReady" />
      </Scene>
    </Renderer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "three": "^0.148.0", "three-gltf-loader": "^1.111.0"

This kind of setup isn't recommended since you can import the latest `GLTFLoader` module from the `three` repository. Try it again with these imports:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
```

Comment: Not work, the only solution is with TroisJS

Answer (score 0):

import like this
`import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'`
Then use like this
`const loader = new GLTFLoader()`